# Using Dark Reader extension code for your own website

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I was scripting dark mode for my own website the hard-code CSS way. And after a couple of hours, I realized the Dark Reader dark mode is more elegant than my own coded dark mode. Is there a way to import that browser toggle script to your own website?[dark reader extension image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUQJW.png)

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but that's not a good idea because it would be *way* harder than doing it yourself and it wouldn't be great for your users because the browser would need to download a lot of code, making the page slower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dark Reader has an official NPM package which you can use to enable dark mode on your website: https://www.npmjs.com/package/darkreader. The unpacked size of the package is currently just 191 KB.

> You can use Dark Reader to enable dark mode on your website!
>
> - Install the package from NPM (`npm install darkreader`)
> - or build from the source code (`npm run api`)
> - or include the script via a CDN such as [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/darkreader/) or [jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/darkreader)
>
> Then use the following API
>
> ```js
> DarkReader.enable({
>     brightness: 100,
>     contrast: 90,
>     sepia: 10
> });
>
> DarkReader.disable();
>
> // Enable when system color scheme is dark.
> DarkReader.auto({
>     brightness: 100,
>     contrast: 90,
>     sepia: 10
> });
>
> // Stop watching for system color scheme.
> DarkReader.auto(false);
>
> // Get the generated CSS of Dark Reader returned as a string.
> const CSS = await DarkReader.exportGeneratedCSS();
> ```
>
> ... or if you are using ES modules
>
> ```js
> import {
>     enable as enableDarkMode,
>     disable as disableDarkMode,
>     auto as followSystemColorScheme,
>     exportGeneratedCSS as collectCSS,
> } from 'darkreader';
>
> enableDarkMode({
>     brightness: 100,
>     contrast: 90,
>     sepia: 10,
> });
>
> disableDarkMode();
>
> followSystemColorScheme();
>
> const CSS = await collectCSS();
> ```

Comment: It doesn't work as well as their plugin though, for instance the js lib doesn't touch inputs whereas their plugin inverts nearly everything.

Comment: This answer is a straight copy-paste of their so called documentation